# How to write a COM EXE for Win32 using Tcl and TclApp?

Tags: perl, com, tcl, activex-exe

I would like to think it possible to use TclApp to create a Win32 EXE that could be used as COM server EXE.

Has anyone tried this, or is it too horrible an idea to seriously consider?

Basically, I want to do in Tcl what I can already do using PerlCtrl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I added to the tcom extension the ability to implement a COM server with Tcl.  Unfortunately, the only documentation for it I got around to writing is
http://www.vex.net/~cthuang/tcom/server.html

Comment: I think I can survive with that amount of documentation. Thank you very much indeed for your prompt and helpful response. Upvote and tick gladly given.